# CASchool students' artworks reflect/reflects ?(Plural)

Tags: grammatical-number

I'm asking about putting "s" at the end in this sentence. Which one is correct? "CASchool students’ artworks  **reflect** their perspectives on road safety." or "CASchool students’ artworks  **reflects** their perspectives on road safety." Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As **artworks** is plural, the singular **reflect** is right for this sentence.

In order to use **reflects** you will have to somehow change the **artworks** to **artwork**, which I wouldn't recommend.